# How do you profile/optimize a simulation tool?

Tags: optimization, profiling, modeling, simulation

In the past, and intermittently now, I've used simulation tools like [Easy Java Simulations](http://www.um.es/fem/EjsWiki/index.php/Main/WhatIsEJS?) and [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/).

They are great tools for visually modeling various mathematical/comp-sci concepts because "all you have to do" is write the simulation loop - the graphics, etc are handled for you.

However, one thing I have noticed is that improving execution time / modeling speed is extremely difficult using such tools, because the guts of the implementation are hidden under the surface.

There is, generally-speaking, great documentation on how to use the simulator tools, but I haven't found anything on improving execution time.

For example, say you're implementing Newton's Method for root finding. It's a straight-forward algorithm, but depending on

- the type of graphic attachment you use, or
- various other miscellaneous options chosen

the simulation will run at different speeds.

Is there a way to determine an "optimal" display of the simulation's data?

I'm thinking of this in the case of using such a tool to teach classes about modeling/scientific programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you can use a combination of these two approaches:

- Second-guess the environment: ask yourself how YOU would implement its features, and then deduce which feature is probably going to require the least computational work.
- Trial-and-error: just compare different methods by testing them out. It's a big help if the environment has some facility for timing your code, such as a function that (accurately) tells you what the time is now.

Don't forget about effects such as memory caching and optimisations. If you try to use a particular feature in a certain context it may run differently to your previous experience.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use the [Repast Symphony](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) agent simulation toolkit.
It is a mature, free, open source programming environment with lots of useful features.
You can integrate Repast with Eclipse what has a [profiler plugin](http://eclipsecolorer.sourceforge.net/index_profiler.html).

Answer (score 2):

With Netlogo, you can use the Profiler extension

```
    extensions [profiler]
```

See [profiler documentation on the netlogo home page](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html)